# Using Colorbox and a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to display a hyperlink that has a colorbox popup associated with it. 
The javascript is:

```
function bid() {    
  var bid = document.getElementById("bid").value;
  if (bid>0 && bid<=100) {
    var per = 3.50;
  } else if (bid>100 && bid<=200) {
    var per = 3.40;
  } else if (bid>200 && bid<=300) {
    var per = 3.30;
  }

 var fee = Math.round(((bid/100)*per)*100)/100;
 var credit = 294.9;

   if (fee>credit) {
     var message = 'Error';
   } else {
     var message = '<a class="popup" href="URL">The link</a>'; 
   }

   document.getElementById("bidText").innerHTML=message;
 }
```

The javascript works fine and displays the link in the right conditions, the problem however is that when clicking the link, the Colorbox isn't being applied and the page loads as a normal hyperlink.

I have the following code in the header:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('a.popup').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
});
```

If I output just the hyperlink in the standard html source, it works fine and displays correctly in the Colorbox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with colorbox, but try altering where it says href="url" to href="#"

Comment: just to confirm, are you loading jquery library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until you've appended the link before you call the `colorbox()` method on it.

Move your `colorbox()` method so that it comes after your `innerHTML`.

```
jQuery('a.popup').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
```

Comment: document.ready is pointless here.  The '.popup' item may or may not be in the DOM when the ready event fires.  Zak's answer is correct, the poster needs to wait until he has added the anchor element to the DOM before querying for it.

Answer (score 0):

when adding html dynamically you, the event added already can not be triggered.
try the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      $("a.popup").on("click", function(event){
      applycolorbox($(this));
});


function applycolorbox($elem) {
         $elem.colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
}
```